# Make 2d drawing from 3d file

Tags: c#, xna

So I have been stuck at this problem for days now, trying to create a 2d drawing from 3d object with xna and c#. I was thinking something like, for example: when you create a picture in paint or what ever and then save that picture to some folder. And set that folder file display(I think that's what its called) to thumbnail, it will show that picture as an icon.

Best regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw the 3D model to a RenderTarget2D and then use that texture however you want.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser, but, could you provide me with a short example? I dont really get it.

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434402.aspx for setting up a rendertarget.  In the example step 4, draw your 3D object (which I assume you already know how to do).  In the example they cast to Texture2D every draw call, but you can just save it as a Texture2D myTex = (Texture2D)renderTarget; one time then reuse that texture wherever you need to display your "icon"

Comment: There are some caveats with alternating between 2D and 3D drawing: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx

Comment: @Beanish Note that the cast to `Texture2D` isn't actually *doing* anything (I imagine it is in the sample for clarity). A `RenderTarget2D` *is* a `Texture2D`. If you want normal "texture" behaviour (most notably automatic handling for device-lost) you need to copy it into one with `GetData` and `SetData`.